# Erasing lines inside polygons

Tags: gimp

In following image:

[image]

I want to make the lines inside the colorful polygons disappear, but leave the line between colorful polygons. For example, inside the green polygon at the right, there are two horizontal yellow lines which I want to remove and make them green like the polygon itself. But I want to leave the lines surrounding the green polygon intact.

I tried to use "eraser", but this changes the yellow lines to transparent lines rather than to green lines.

I tried to use "smudge", but this blends the yellow with the green and creates a dirty-looking image.

What can I do?

Comment: That's fine, but how accurate do you need to be?  For instance, in the green and cyan square there is a dark blue line. Do you give preference to the cyan or the green, or use a mid line?

Comment: Between different colors, I do not care about the lines. All I want is that, inside each color, there will be no visible lines.

Comment: The easiest way would be to create a new transparent layer, then just paint over the lines using a hard brush and set the color via the eyedropper.

Comment: Is the area you have to do this on just what we can see here, or a much larger image, or many more of them? For the part we can see, this would be a 15 minutes tops job with a hard brush in any suitable application.

Answer (score 1):

Select the lines individually with the magic wand tool and fill will choice color to remove line and replace with the fill.

This type of drawing is best created and edited in Adobe illustrator-- you could probably re-create very quickly by importing your image as a jpg or pdf as a template and tracing shapes with tool set.  Adobe illustrator is resolution independent and can scale to any size without degradation.

Comment: Or inckscape which is more probable for somebody using gimp.

Comment: In the question is required to erase the *yellow* lines *inside* the green area. Using the magic wand tool will select the borders (which are connected) too. In my opinion your answer should be revised a little, e.g. suggesting to use the rectangular selection to limit the action of the magic wand or using a support layer as PieBie suggest, or...

Answer (score 1):

Use a hard brush of appropriate size, pick the color from the corresponding adjacent area, and paint the lines away.

Zoom in at the ends for pixel-perfectness.